# Driver video NVIDIA nvidia-173 uninstallable on 12.10 Quantal Quetzal

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 12.10

Packages are available from the archive but uninstallable.

nvidia-173 :
Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 or xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable
Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 1):

A newer 173 release [173.14.36 seems to support v13 abi](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/linux-display-amd64-173.14.36-driver-uk.html). It seems like Ubuntu integrators have allowed the package to break by moving xorg to v13 when there's no v13 nvidia 173 driver out yet.

There seems to be some progress in [bug #1064192](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173/+bug/1064192), although it's been roughly a month with all (new) installs on machines with these Nvidia cards being broken. It seems to be a recurring thing with Ubuntu if you look around.

Comment: I've installed the 64bit version but whe I reboot:
1) It's evereything black so I have to put "nomodeset" after "quiet splash" in grub configuration.
2) Xorg fail and system says:
"The system is running in low-graphics mode
Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself."
3) After it says "What you like to do?" so I tried to reconfigure graphics loading a new config or a backup one but it fails again so now it run only if I select "Run in low-graphics mode for just one session" every time I have to turn on my PC.